# Swift storyboard: changing a two column layout to a multiple column layout

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I made an iOS app that has multiple textfields, arranged in side-by-side pattern, or a two column layout. The conditions are the textfields must have 40 pixels in between each other, and as a leading and trailing space to the view.

But now, I'm tasked with changing some of the textfields, such that they will be divided into three.

Behold, my client's dark wishes:

[image]

Please excuse my terrifying paint skills, but the gist of this is that there still needs to be 40 pixels in between the textfields. Their lengths can be a variable, though preferably equal to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use UIStackView here.

1) Grab these 3 textfields into a StackView

2) Set the StackView length equal to the textfield above/below, so it simply inherit its size

3) Set the distance between textfields in StackView to 40 pixels

4) Set each textfield length equal to the remaining two textfields, so they always keep the same aspect ratio

I hope I understood your problem well

Comment: BTW, suppose I were to put an image over a textfield (an arrow downwards), how would I do so? Adding the image messes up the constraints something fierce.

Comment: You have to experiment with that, try putting image outside the stackview and tweak constraints

Comment: I put both the textview and the image to go over it inside another view. Did the trick.